# two setTimeout under one function

Tags: jquery, ajax, settimeout

i am trying to get notifications for a small project of mine using setTimeout but it requires me to get two types of notification 1. messages 2.global  so i had to write two functions , is this possible to use two setTimeout under one function here is what i coded

```
// Message Notification Poll 


(function pollmsg() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var demon = $('.msgnotimore').val();
        var page = "notimsg";
        var a = $('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'modules/notifications/beast.php?nid=' + demon + '&id=' + a + '&page=' + page,
            success: function (html) {
                if ($.trim(html) == 'no') {}
                else {
                    $('.msgnotimore').remove();
                    $('.notiloadmsg').prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow'));
                }
            },
            dataType: "html",
            complete: pollmsg
        });
    }, 60000);
})();
// Global Notification Poll
(function pollglobal() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var demon = $('.globalnotimore').val();
        var page = "notiglobal";
        var a = $('.gvpgvpxgvp').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'modules/notifications/beast.php?nid=' + demon + '&id=' + a + '&page=' + page,
            success: function (html) {
                if ($.trim(html) == 'no') {}
                else {
                    $('.globalnotimore').remove();
                    $('.notiloadglobal').prepend($(html).fadeIn('slow'));
                }
            },
            dataType: "html",
            complete: pollglobal
        });
    }, 60000);
})();
```

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense. Perhaps you want to combine the two `setTimeout` callbacks into a single one?

Comment: no i want to use one function named notification under which two setimeout can be there. is this possible and is there any other way to reduce the code

Comment: You have two different setTimeouts that both have the same delay. there is no reason not to combine the two into one. It would be even better if you turn it into a function where you simply pass in the data you wish to use as `demon` `page` and `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking 'is it ok to have two setTimeouts running at once'?

If this is the question then the answer is yes, you can have as many setTimeouts running at once as you like.  I believe the only limit is memory.

Comment: well i wanted to know a better code for what i coded ,i mean using one function instead of 2 different for 2 different setTimeout is this possible

Comment: Well, yes. You can put the two setTimeouts on two lines in the same function. e.g. delete the part in your example that says '})();
// Global Notification Poll
(function pollglobal() {'